# after-update trigger in mysql 5.5.40

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

It's my first time that I try to use trigger on mysql (and generally I don't use mysql so much).

The version of mysql that I'm using is 5.5.40 and the code I'm using to create the trigger is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateTrigger
AFTER UPDATE ON tab1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   UPDATE tab2
   SET field1 = NEW.field1
   WHERE field2 = NEW.field2;
END;
```

Where field1 and field2 are two fields in both tables (tab1 and tab2) both archer(120).

When I try to execute this code I receive an error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7
```

(line 7 is near "WHEN" keyword).

I checked several answer on stack overflow and other web sites, I tried with and without delimiters, and I still not able to create a trigger.

What's my syntax error?

Is there some way to have some more accurate mysql debugging? Actually mysql answer (like I just posted) is just "there is an error (1064)" but it doesn't let me know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the delimiter to use it in your sql statement :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER updateTrigger
AFTER UPDATE ON tab1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   UPDATE tab2
   SET field1 = NEW.field1
   WHERE field2 = NEW.field2;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, I tried to use your suggestion and now I don't have the error that I did receive before, but it still doesn't work. Now I receive a new error: `#1142 - TRIGGER command denied to user '---' for table 'tab1'`, also if I try to execute it as admin. Do you have some suggestion for that?

Comment: first, see if your server support trigger by executing this query :   `show privileges`  
if triggers is listed, you have to grant trigger privilege to administrator. 
(you can check user priviliges by typing : `show grants for 'yourAdminOrUserLogin'` in the console)
Assuming you use phpMyAdmin, click on Privileges then edit user privileges and check the privilege you want to grant